# Create response body in ObjectResult

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET Core, just a question on ObjectResult. I saw sone code like this:

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
 {
    var myerror = new
    {
       Success = false,
       Errors = new [] { context.Exception.Message }
    };
    context.Result = new ObjectResult(myerror)
    {
        StatusCode = 500
    };
    context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    ...
 }
```

my questions are:

1- is the property 'Errors' anonymous type of object "myerror" creating the response body with the exception's message?

2. It seems that I can use any names for properties not just 'Success; and 'Errors' so can I code like:

```
 var myerror = new
    {
       mySuccess = false,
       myErrors = new [] { context.Exception.Message }
    };
```

is it OK?

3. whats the purpose of doing `context.ExceptionHandled = true;`? the book says Marks the exception as handled to prevent it propagating out of MvcMiddleware. But why it need to prevent it propagating out?

Comment: Please don't put tags into question title, it brings no additional information to the regular tags you can add below the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) Yes, it is okay. You can create object of any structure you want, not only anonymous objects.

```
public class ErrorModel
{
    public string Error { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<int> Values { get; set; }
}

//filter

var error = new ErrorModel
{
    Error = context.Exception.Message,
    Id = 1,
    Values = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }
};
context.Result = new ObjectResult(error)
{
    StatusCode = 500
};
```

3) It is possible that there are multiple exception filters in your application and if you don't set `ExceptionHandled` to `true` while processing an exception then every filter get called and `Result` is overriden. The purpose of this property is to indicate that certain filter was able to cope with exception and there is no need to run other exception filters. It is useful in scenarious when filter can handle only certain types of exception.

```
//handles only exceptions caused by dividing by zero
public class DivideByZeroExceptionFilterAttribute : Attribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //chech if this is divide by zero exception
        if (!(context.Exception is DivideByZeroException))
            return;

        var myerror = new
        {
            result = false,
            message = "Division by zero went wrong"
        };
        context.Result = new ObjectResult(myerror)
        {
            StatusCode = 500
        };

        //set "handled" to true since exception is already property handled
        //and there is no need to run other filters
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. could you also have a look at this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567481/configureservices-and-configure